# Image scan - message queing - performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scala, node.js, playframework, message-queue

I am planning to build a web site which has lot to do with .

1. Images uploaded by mobile user .
2. Messaging to end users .

What would be my best storage options with respect to images that customers upload from their mobile systems. Should it be amazon s3 ?

For fast retrieval and response which technology options would be best . Node.js ? Asp.net mvc , play -japid .

With respect to having a mobile messaging solution .  What would be recommended way to build a message queuing system.  Play - AKKa  ?

One thing here is that i dont mind spending time to learn .

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Images uploaded by mobile user.
>   What would be my best storage options with respect to images that
>   customers upload from their mobile systems. Should it be amazon s3 ?

It could be S3 or any other [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). You could also host the images yourself using for example [NGinx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) with [upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html). [To boost performance you could also use Memcached module for NGinx](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/). When you host yourself I think you have better control over the costs. I don't think I advice you (yet) to use node.js to do image uploading because ["Node sucks at serving large
files." => Slide 14](http://nodejs.org/jsconf2010.pdf).

> Messaging to end users.

I would recommend you to have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io).

> With respect to having a mobile messaging solution . What would be
>   recommended way to build a message queuing system. Play - AKKa ?

I would not built a message queuing system, because there are already a lot of very efficient message queues. You could very example use [redis](http://redis.io), [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) or [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as your message queue. You could also use redis to cache your data or [memcached](http://memcached.org/).